# Legend for scatter plot - Label what each shape represents

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter graph which plots two set of values - `valList1` and `valList2`

```
plt.scatter(valList1, numList, marker='^', c='green')
plt.scatter(valList2, numList, marker='o', c='red')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Degrees')
plt.show()
```

I want to generate a legend which marks that `^` represents `val1` and `o` represents `val2`.

In a normal plot I can assign `label` values like `label = "val1 Values"` but I'm unable to figure out how to do that for the case of scatter plot. Help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.scatter` instead of `plt.scatter`

```
one = np.random.randn(10,2)
two = np.random.randn(10,2)+5
valList1,numList1 = one.T
valList2,numList2 = two.T

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(valList1, numList1, marker='^', c='green', label='^')
ax.scatter(valList2, numList2, marker='o', c='red', label='o')
ax.set_xlabel('Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Degrees')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

the output is

[image: output]

Comment: Can you please explain what `fig` and `vs` represent respectively?

Comment: @krtkush according to https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html, `fig` is a `Figure` object, and `ax`, in this case, is an `Axes` object.